# how to convert a list with different length of lists to a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a list containing three different length of vectors with unique elements for each vector.

```
data <- list(ARG=letters[1:8],BRZ=c("a","b","c","f","h","g","l","m","n"),US=c("u","b","c","e","h","f","q","a","n","t"))
```

I would like to convert this list to a data frame by mergering them together, the result is expected as below or similar output, Thank you for helping this.

```
    ID  ARG BRZ US
    a   1   1   1
    b   1   1   1
    c   1   1   1
    d   1       
    e   1       1
    f   1   1   1
    g   1   1   
    h   1   1   1
    l       1   
    m       1   
    n       1   1
    q           1
    t           1
    u           1
```

Comment: You need `library(qdapTools);t(mtabulate(data))`

Comment: @akrun perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `mtabulate` and transpose the output

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(data))
```

---

Or if we are using `base R`, then `stack` into a `data.frame` with 2 columns and apply the `table`

```
table(stack(data))
```

Assuming that there are no duplicates for each entry.  If there are duplicates, then we may need a logical vector coerced to binary

```
+(table(stack(data)) >0)
```